# MacOS: Symbol not found: _libiconv when run sudo command

Tags: macos

I met this error when trying to run "sudo" command on MacOS:

```
> sudo           
dyld[89850]: Symbol not found: _libiconv
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
[1]    89850 abort      sudo
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is this the standard sudo or one you installed yourself?

Comment: I think it's standard.

Comment: Run `which sudo` in terminal

Comment: If `/opt/local/lib` is mentioned it's probably a partially incomplete MacPorts install. It may be the macOS `sudo` finding a symlink in an old MacPorts `lib`, whereas the macOS `sudo` expects it in `/usr/lib'. There may be some library path shenanigans going on.

Comment: I'd also ask you to update the question with  the output of `/usr/bin/sudo otool -L $(which sudo)`, but as it's likely to fail if you think your system is using the standard one, given your primary problem, it may be difficult. If you have MacPorts installed, I'd suggest following its uninstall instructions and then reinstalling. Please update your question with your version of macOS, and what hardware.